# Do all browsers render jQuery-induced inline style HEX colors as RGB

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I wrote a unit-test for an angular JS directive, and everything seemed fine, except a particular error, that was caused by me using a HEX notation, and the browser converting in to rgb notation.

`Error: Expected 'rgb(238, 238, 238)' to equal '#EEEEEE'.`
You may notice that the above RGB and HEX expression stand for the same color precisely, and the difference.

So my question is:
Can I use rgb notation, and assume that it will be testable on all the browsers, or do I need to manually detect the notation type, and convert one of the colors to match the notation of the other one manually

I also found [this git-hub issue](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery/issues/75).

Comment: Older browsers don't understand `rgb()` colors. For testing, probably the safest thing is to have the test know how to normalize two different representations.

Comment: ... IE9 was the first IE to understand `rgb()` colors. Thus your code, if it wants to work in IE8 and below, has to use the hash notation. However, some browsers *report* colors in `rgb()` no matter how you code them. (You probably know that by now :)

Comment: The information you supplied about supported color notations in various browsers is useful, I think you should post it as an answer.
My application only supports IE 9 and beyond, and even this through many fallbacks(cors, XMLHTTPRequest2, Placeholder tag an many others)